# WARNING: Exhausted all input expected for the current sequence while reading a floating point value at offset

Tags: cntk

I'm trying this [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt791798) of CNTK but it fails when training the data... 
It seems that it exhausted all input but that is somehow handled as an error.
I have no idea what is going wrong. Anyone can help?

**Error**

```
WARNING: Exhausted all input expected for the current sequence while reading a floating point value at offset 790 in the input file (TrainData.txt)

[CALL STACK]                                                                                                                > Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::IDataReader::  SupportsDistributedMBRead
    - Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::IDataReader::  SupportsDistributedMBRead                                                        - Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::IDataReader::  SupportsDistributedMBRead
    - Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::IDataReader::  SupportsDistributedMBRead                                                        - Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::IDataReader::  SupportsDistributedMBRead
    - CreateDeserializer                                                                                                    - CreateDeserializer
    - CreateDeserializer                                                                                                    - CreateDeserializer
    - CreateDeserializer                                                                                                    - CreateDeserializer
    - CreateDeserializer                                                                                                    - CreateDeserializer
    - CreateDeserializer                                                                                                    - CreateDeserializer
    - CreateDeserializer
EXCEPTION occurred: Reached the maximum number of allowed errors while reading the input file (TrainData.txt).
```

**TestData.txt**

```
|features 1.0 1.0 |labels 1 0 0
|features 3.0 9.0 |labels 1 0 0
|features 8.0 8.0 |labels 1 0 0
|features 3.0 4.0 |labels 0 1 0
|features 5.0 6.0 |labels 0 1 0
|features 3.0 6.0 |labels 0 1 0
|features 8.0 3.0 |labels 0 0 1
|features 8.0 1.0 |labels 0 0 1
|features 9.0 2.0 |labels 0 0 1
```

**TrainData.txt**

```
|features 1.0 5.0 |labels 1 0 0
|features 1.0 2.0 |labels 1 0 0
|features 3.0 8.0 |labels 1 0 0
|features 4.0 1.0 |labels 1 0 0
|features 5.0 8.0 |labels 1 0 0
|features 6.0 3.0 |labels 1 0 0
|features 7.0 5.0 |labels 1 0 0
|features 7.0 6.0 |labels 1 0 0
|features 1.0 4.0 |labels 1 0 0
|features 2.0 7.0 |labels 1 0 0
|features 2.0 1.0 |labels 1 0 0
|features 3.0 1.0 |labels 1 0 0
|features 5.0 2.0 |labels 1 0 0
|features 6.0 7.0 |labels 1 0 0
|features 7.0 4.0 |labels 1 0 0
|features 3.0 5.0 |labels 0 1 0
|features 4.0 4.0 |labels 0 1 0
|features 5.0 5.0 |labels 0 1 0
|features 4.0 6.0 |labels 0 1 0
|features 4.0 5.0 |labels 0 1 0
|features 6.0 1.0 |labels 0 0 1
|features 7.0 1.0 |labels 0 0 1
|features 8.0 2.0 |labels 0 0 1
|features 7.0 2.0 |labels 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Got an answer from someone offline.

Each well-formed line must end with either a "Line Feed" \n or "Carriage Return, Line Feed" \r\n symbols (including the last line of the file).

[CNTK TextFormat-Reader](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/CNTKTextFormat-Reader).